# Two subnets on one LAN

Tags: subnet, tcpip

I have a simple 192.168.1.x/24 LAN

GW & DNS = 192.168.1.254

My workstation is 192.168.1.101

I wish to setup a parallel mirror LAN for testing using a 192.168.10.x/24 subnet on the same switch.

Question 1
Can computers on the testing LAN use the 192.168.1.254 GW & DNS?

Question 2
What is required for me to be able to communicate between the two subnets?
i.e. I need to browse from my workstation to a server on the testing subnet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Question 1 Can computers on the testing LAN use the 192.168.1.254 GW & DNS?

Not the gateway, since they're in seperate networks. DNS can be used if the DNS server is reachable.

> Question 2 What is required for me to be able to communicate between the two subnets? i.e. I need to browse from my workstation to a server on the testing subnet

You need a *router*, which has interfaces in both networks and is able to forward packets between them.

Comment: On a related note, the router can be your current default gateway with an alias address in the 192.168.10.0/24 network. If you are using an off-the-shelf consumer router model, this kind of configuration likely will be not supported. Either a hackier configuration (like with pf/OPNsense or OpenWRT) or an enterprise-grade router model will allow for it, though.